# Oracle commitlog

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I'm having what I suspect is a race-condition in an Oracle application I inherited. Is there any way to see when commits against a table was made? I don't care what was changed (at least not for now), I only want to know if a commit was made within a certain timespan.

Comment: you can use logminer

Comment: Is there no way to do it in sql? It's a fairly locked-down environment, getting access to anything new takes a while...

Comment: Not sure if that helps in your case, but in Oracle you have `ORA_ROWSCN` pseudo-column that holds the most recent change to the row and can be used to get timestamp (with `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` function) .

Comment: @a1ex07 wouldn't that give him the time a transaction started?  But maybe that's good enough for the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may query v$logmnr_contents, as per documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm#i1016607

```
SELECT SQL_REDO FROM V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS
 WHERE
 SEG_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES' AND
 SEG_OWNER = 'HR' AND
 OPERATION = 'UPDATE' AND
 DBMS_LOGMNR.MINE_VALUE(REDO_VALUE, 'HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY') >
 2*DBMS_LOGMNR.MINE_VALUE(UNDO_VALUE, 'HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY');
```

But remember that the data is changed immediately, not on commit!  Until commit, other sessions see the data as it was before, or receive an error if Oracla can no longer show it ("rollback segment too small").